# Compatibility of pullbacks with an equivalence relation

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topology, pullback, sites

*This question was originally posted last week in Math Stack Exchange (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483240/compatibility-of-pullbacks-with-an-equivalence-relation)).*

I'm currently working on the proof of the existence of the sheafification in Angelo Vistoli’s 2007 [*Notes on Grothendieck topologies,
fibered categories
and descent theory*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412512.pdf), but i currently stuck on a statement in the proof of Theorem 2.64. $(ii)$. That is the following:

Note: In this context, a Grothendieck topology is a Singleton Grothendieck topology, such that every covering of an object $U$ in $C$ is a single map $\phi:T\rightarrow U$.

We have a site $C$, that is a category $C$ with a Grothendieck topology. Then we have a functor $$F:C^{op}\rightarrow Set$$
We define an equivalence relation $\sim$ for every object $U$ of $C$ on $F(U)$ as: $a\sim b$ if there exists a covering $\phi:T\rightarrow U$, such that the pullback $F(\phi)=\phi^*$ of $a$ and $b$ coincide in $F(T)$. In other words $\phi^*(a)=\phi^*(b)$.
Now the statement is, that for every morphism $f:S\rightarrow U$ the pullback $F(f)=f^*:F(U)\rightarrow F(S)$ is compatible with $\sim$. That means:
$$
a,b\in F(U):a\sim b\Rightarrow f^*(a)\sim f^*(b)
$$

**Question:** How do I prove this?

Comment: You haven't used any of the covering axioms. You probably also need the pullback pasting lemma.

Comment: Thank you for your response. With that information i got, that $pr_1$ and $pr_2$ are monomorphism and coverings. I'm not even sure my proof is on target. But i will keep trying.

Comment: It would have been better to post your proof as an answer on Sept 1 rather than editing the question to include that proof. Now we have a question with no answer and no way to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I saw my mistake I got the proof really quick. We need the fibre product of $f$ and $\phi$, where $f$ is an arbitrarily morphism and $\phi$ the covering from $a\sim b$.
So we get the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S\times_UT @>{pr_2}>> T\\
@V{pr_1}VV @VV{\phi}V\\
S @>{f}>> U
\end{CD}

hence
$$
\phi\circ pr_2=f\circ pr_1.
$$
Using $F$ on both sides we get
$$
F(\phi\circ pr_2)=F(f\circ pr_1)\quad\text{ or }\quad pr_2^*\circ\phi^*=pr_1^*\circ f^*.
$$
Hence, $pr_1^*(f^*(a))=(pr_1^*\circ f^*)(a)=pr_2^*(\phi^*(a))=pr_2^*(\phi^*(b))=(pr_1^*\circ f^*)(b)=pr_1^*(f^*(b)).$

Since $pr_1$ is a covering (Covering Axioms), we get $f^*(a)\sim f^*(b)$.

q.e.d.